# Stock Trading Expected Value Calculation

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have a stock at a price of 100 whose minimum price increment is 1. Assume that at any price we have equal probability of moving up or down. In other words, model the stock price as a discrete random walk with step size 1.

We buy 1 share with a stop at 99. In other words, if the price reaches 99 we lose 1 dollar and exit the trade. However, also assume that if the price reaches 102 before it reaches 99, we begin to keep half of the maximum profit achieved during the lifetime of the trade, and our stop moves accordingly. For example, if we hit 102, we move our stop to 101 and thus guarantee a profit greater than or equal to 1 dollar. If before it reaches 101 the price reaches 103 instead, we attempt to keep half (1.5) of the max profit (3), but since the minimum price increment is 1, it is impossible to lose 1.5 dollars, so our exit condition is losing 1.5 or more. In this case, to lose 1.5 from 103 would put us at 101.5, and the closest possible stock price to that that satisfies the exit condition is 101. Therefore in this case we would keep 1 dollar of profit. If the price reaches 104, our stop moves to 102, and we guarantee a profit greater than or equal to 2 dollars, and so on. This pattern continues until the stop price is hit as our exit condition.

How do we calculate the expected profit of the trade?

Comment: Try to isolate the mathematical question from the given more or less financial setting. The problem to be solved is first of all not clear. What does it mean "we buy with a stop at $99$"? (Given that the stock is at $100$, more than $99$ *when* do we stop? We buy at each "step" one stock share? How long? We have capital $100$ at time zero and buy and sell in the same time at each step? Please make clear what capital we have and how to compute the win after one, respectively after all steps till the floor $99$ is hit.)

Comment: Does "greater" include "equal". If price becomes 101, do we take 0.5 or wait for it to become 102?

Comment: @dan_fulea We buy with a stop at 99 means we buy at a price of 100 and if it goes to 99 we exit the trade at a loss of 1 point. This only applies in the case where it goes down immediately. If it instead goes to 101 before 99, we move our stop to 100.5 and keep a 1/2 point profit. If it goes to 102, our stop moves to 101. Is this clear now?

Comment: @dan_fulea We do not buy more than once, and that buy is the initial buy at 100.

Comment: @dan_fulea No mention is made of the capital in the account because it is irrelevant. It is just a scaling factor applied to the number of points gained or lost due to the price action. If you buy x shares at 100 and make 10 points, you have 10x profit. If you have 10 times as much money and buy 10x shares, your profit is 100x. We instead just look at the 10 point price movement.

Comment: The question is still unclear for me. The above comments gives a lot of sense to the practical situation, thanks for adding the details, it is a good idea to add these details as part of the question (at the right points in the flow of the story). This may moderate the adverse reaction of readers in position to vote for closing this question. (There are three votes so far.) Closing the question is frustration for all sides, please prevent this by *editing*. I am missing a formula for the profit. For instance in case of a $UUDDUUUD\dots$ which is the profit, and when we stop? (U=up, D=down.)

Comment: @Veliko Please reread the question; I have added details that I hope make the problem clear.

Comment: @dan_fulea With the new problem formulation with step size 1, UUDDUUUD would correspond to a price action like this: 101 102 101 100 101 102 103 102. Since at 102 points we activate the stop that keeps half the max profit during the lifetime of the trade, we would exit at a profit of 1 dollar when the price reaches 101 again. Please let me know if there is anything left unclear in the question. I did my best to explain every detail.

Comment: Are you familiar with the optional stopping theorem? It implies the expected profit is zero.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I read about it and somewhat see how it applies but I still would like if you posted an answer to the question applying it to the problem situation.